# Python: Parallelize for loop reading lines from file

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a csv document 'A' with 150 million lines where I need to check the words on each line against the words of another textfile 'B': If the word is in both A and B, it should export the whole line of A into a new file.

I have put all the words of B into a list and check A against it line by line. Naturally this cries out for parallelization.

My code is simple:

```
keylist = []
for word in keyfile.read().split():
    if not isInt(word):
        keylist.append(word)
linenotadded = True
for line in tagfile:
    for word in line.split(', '):
        if linenotadded:
            if not isID(word):
                if word in keylist:
                    fout.write(line)
                    linenotadded=False
    linenotadded=True
```

How can I easily parallelize the for-loop? I have plenty of cores and memory as I am working on a HPC platform.

Comment: before crying for parallelization, put your `keylist` in a `set()` instead of a `list` an observe the speed increase.

Comment: as a more general remark, optimize your loops first (using listcomps, less flags, whatever) before thinking of parallelizing that. I suspect that reading from disk will be a bottleneck unless you store the various part of your files on several SDD disks :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre using set() instead of list made it much faster. What is the reason?

Comment: dichotomic lookup on elements hashes instead of linear lookup.